In SSMS SP debugger, can "Watch" variable value length be increased above 255 character limit
I need to monitor (in Local or in Watch) a varchar(max) field where the value length is approximately 500 characters.  But when I try to view or copy/paste the value, only the first 255 characters are there.  How can I change this limit so I can view the entire value instead of only part of it?  I even tried debugging in VS2019, but I still experience this same value length limit.  (I can use either VS or SSMS 2012).

Why are you still using SSMS 2012? You're literally 14 years behind in releases, as SSMS 20 was released earlier this year.

Hello @ThomA, we are actually using that version only for debugging SPs.  Otherwise, we use SSMS 20.  We also use VS2019 to debug SPs.  If there's a better way, please let me know.  In the meantime, any way to change the Watch variable length limit besides using the HTML visualizer?

If you want to view the entire length of the varchar(max) Watch/local variable, you can also right click the value and select Copy Value (not Copy) and paste them into notepad file. You will see the entire length of your variable.

But i think the best way to view the entire length of the variable is to use view icon to view them in different formats.
UPDATE
If you want to use SSMS2012 only for debugging SPs, i suggest you to  debug it in Visual Studio instead.
Right click your database projcet->Add->Stored Procedure
Press the drop-down arrow on the green arrow button in the Transact-SQL editor toolbar and select Execute with Debugger to execute the query with debugging on.

For more information, please refer to :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/how-to-debug-stored-procedures?view=sql-server-ver15#to-debug-stored-procedures

Thank you Dou, however it seems that option does not exist, perhaps because I am using SSMS 2012 to debug the SP (as a note, I am using SSMS as an admin).  The options that are available when I right click are:  Copy, Edit Value (grayed out), Add Watch, Select All, Hexadecimal display, and Collapse Parent (grayed out).  No "Copy Value" is available.  What version of SSMS are you using?

I am using SSMS 20.0. I debugged in VS 2022 Community.

Hi James, updated the answer.

Maybe not the most efficient way, but instead of using the 'Text Visualizer', I used the 'HTML Visualizer', and was able to view the entire length of the varchar(max) Watch/Local variable.


" Does anyone have a better solution?" Is this an answer or an extension of your question? If the former it should be asking a question, if the latter then edit your question; answers are for answers.

Agree - I updated the text to just show the answer.  But I would like to know if there is a better way of viewing the Watch variable value.
